# vb.net easiest way to store multidimensional data

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

i am wondering if what is the easiest way to store multidimensional data

when i am retrieving records from the database, I use an array to store some information that i will use later like this

```
rowCtr = 0
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    md(rowCtr, 0) = dr("member_id").ToString
    md(rowCtr, 1) = dr("full_name").ToString
    md(rowCtr, 2) = dr("status").ToString
    md(rowCtr, 3) = dr("archived").ToString

    ...

    rowCtr = rowCtr + 1
Next
```

to access data of a specific member, i use this

```
'first i loop through the md array to get the array index (ind) of a member
'then, i can get the data of a member by using this
md(ind, 0) 'To get the id
md(ind, 1) 'To get the full name
```

it's kinda hard because i always need to know and specify the index

i want it to be like this

```
md("443", "full_name") 'to get the full name
md("443", "status") 'to get the status
```

where 443 is a member id, i use it as the key of the first dimension

i have read about hashtables, dictionary, list - but i can't seem to find a good example on using them in a multi dimensional style

if possible, i also want the length to be dynamic, and when i delete an index, the rest will fill it's spot -

i also need it to have a search method to find if the member_id is already in the list

what is the easiest way to do it? please reply .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother copying the data to the array - just use the `DataTable` directly:

```
Dim drMatch() As DataRow = dt.Select("member_id='443'")
If drMatch.GetUpperBound(0) >= 0 Then
  MsgBox(drMatch(0).Item("full_name").ToString)
End If
```

If you are assembling data from different sources into your array, I'd define a new in-memory `DataTable` to use, instead of your array.

Answer (score 1):

if you have to save it as an array (not sure why you would) you could use ENUM:

```
 Enum Table1
  Member_ID = 1
  Full_Name = 2
  Status = 3
  archived = 4
 End Enum
```

then in your array you could do this:

```
 md("443", Table1.Full_Name) 'to get the full name
  md("443", Table1.Status) 'to get the status
```